# Why is this query giving me a syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, bigdata, pentaho

Everytime I try to compile this code on DBeaver, it gives me a syntax error right where the first AND statement is located. I don't know how to solve it.

```
SELECT  idintervento as _IDInterventoRif, idcdc, idcartella,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT idintervento) as nInt
        FROM cch.pats_cch_interventi i
        WHERE (idtiporecord in('UTI','INT'))
            AND i.idcdc           =  inter.idcdc
            AND i.idcartella      =  inter.idcartella
            AND i.utiingressodata <  inter.utiingressodata
            AND i.idintervento    <> inter.idintervento 
     ) as _IDInterventoTipoN

FROM  cch.pats_cch_interventi inter
WHERE  (idtiporecord in('INT') OR idtiporecord IS NULL)
    AND idintervento    <> ?
    AND idcdc           =  ?
    AND idcartella      =  ?
    AND (dataintervento <  ? 
            OR dataintervento = ? AND idintervento < ?)

ORDER BY idcdc, idcartella, utiingressodata desc;
```

Comment: Please add the error message  in full.

Comment: BTW 'AND (dataintervento <  ? 
            OR dataintervento = ? AND idintervento < ?)' - mixing ands an ors like this is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Error SQL [42601]: Syntax Error by "AND"

Comment: In your query what is the '?' question mark meaning, If it's as string than add single quetes over the question mark. otherwise give proper value in where clause with feilds.

Comment: @VegaOmega . . . That error code suggests that the underlying database is Postgres, so the MySQL tag is quite confusing.  Sometimes these types of problems are due to a bad character (that you cannot see) and retyping the code fixes the issue.

Comment: I'm not a Postgres user, but I've never seen in(value1,value2) without a space after the IN operator. Also, the idtiporecord should probably be i.idtiporecord, since it's ambiguous otherwise.

Comment: Show us the query after the `?`s are filled in.

Comment: Show us the complete error message.  Not that `near` really means that.  It is pointing at the error or just after the offending token.